# How can I only have a single move command in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an existing batch file that attempts to move files from 2 directories to 2 different locations. At the moment these are called as 2 separate move commands. I am wanting to simply the code further and was wondering if there was a way to do so

```
@echo off
for %%a in (C:\Test\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" move /Y "C:\Test\%%~na%%~xa" "D:\Done" 
for %%i in (C:\Sample\*.*) do if "%%~xi" == "" move /Y "C:\Sample\%%~ni%%~xi" "D:\Done"
```

The other scenario is when the destination paths are different as follows

```
@echo off
for %%a in (C:\Test\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" move /Y "C:\Test\%%~na%%~xa" "D:\Done" 
for %%i in (C:\Sample\*.*) do if "%%~xi" == "" move /Y "C:\Sample\%%~ni%%~xi" "E:\Done"
```

Comment: I am not convinced that shorter==simpler but you can use `for %%a in (c:\Test\*.* C:\Sample\*.*) do` and then extract the correct directory during the `mv`.

Comment: @Paul - Been a while. Hope all is well. I currently have 5 batch files that do similar tasks hence wanted to simplify it further. For example rather than hardcoding the path, like to have variables I can reference. How would that work if they have to be moved to 2 separate directories?

Comment: Your question shows them going to the same directory - can you [edit] and add some more scenarios?

Comment: @Paul - I have updated the question.

Comment: I agree with paul.  You gain nothing by making the code shorter.  You only make troubleshooting more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing command:

```
for %%a in (C:\Test\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" move /Y "C:\Test\%%~na%%~xa" "D:\Done"
```

Says "if the file has no extension then move it to d:\Done" - it isn't clear why you are doing the name and extension tests in the move.  It looks like this would be just as effective:

```
for %%a in (C:\Test\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" move /Y "%%a" "D:\Done"
```

In which case, this would do both directories in the same line:

```
for %%a in (C:\Test\*.* C:\Sample\*.*) do if "%%~xa" == "" move /Y "%%a" "D:\Done"
```

As for picking different destination directories, it would depend entirely what the criteria was.

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer. The criteria is based on the source destination.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Your only option would be to do an 'if' inside the loop and pick a different destination based on the source folder. It would be more efficient and readable (simpler) to two this as two separate loops.  The string manipulation would be pretty unreadable, and so doesn't meet the question requirement of simplification.